# typedef enum type as key to NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

Are enums not allowed as keys for an NSMutableDictionary?

When I try to add to the dictionary via:

```
[self.allControllers setObject:aController forKey:myKeyType];
```

I get the error:

> error: incompatible type for argument
>   2 of 'setObject:forKey:'

Typically, I use NSString as my key name which doesn't require a cast to 'id' but to make the error go away, I had do that. Is the casting the correct behavior here or are enums as keys a bad idea?

My enum is defined as:

```
typedef enum tagMyKeyType
{
  firstItemType = 1,
  secondItemType = 2
} MyKeyType;
```

And the dictionary is defined and properly allocated as such:

```
NSMutableDictionary *allControllers;

allControllers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: why don't you just use an array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can store the enum in an NSNumber though. (Aren't enums just ints?)

```
[allControllers setObject:aController forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt: firstItemType]];
```

In Cocoa, const NSStrings are often used. In the .h you would declare something like:

```
NSString * const kMyTagFirstItemType;
NSString * const kMyTagSecondtItemType;
```

And in the .m file you would put

```
NSString * const kMyTagFirstItemType = @"kMyTagFirstItemType";
NSString * const kMyTagSecondtItemType = @"kMyTagSecondtItemType";
```

Then you can use it as a key in a dictionary.

```
[allControllers setObject:aController forKey:kMyTagFirstItemType];
```

Comment: I think you want to use the `extern` keyword in the .h file here, correct?

Comment: You can also use `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` as the keyword which I believe is typedef'd to `extern` as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but can be updated to use a more modern syntax. Firstly, as of iOS 6, Apple recommends that enums be defined as:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum) {
   MyEnumValue1 = -1, // default is 0
   MyEnumValue2,  // = 0 Because the last value is -1, this auto-increments to 0
   MyEnumValue3 // which means, this is 1
};
```

Then, since we have the enum represented as `NSInteger`s internally, we can box them into `NSNumber`s to store as the key for a dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// set the value
dictionary[@(MyEnumValue1)] = @"test";

// retrieve the value
NSString *value = dictionary[@(MyEnumValue1)];
```

**EDIT: How to create a singleton dictionary for this purpose**

Through this method, you can create a singleton dictionary to assist with this. At the top of whatever file you have, you can use:

```
static NSDictionary *enumTranslations;
```

Then in your `init` or `viewDidLoad` (if you're doing this in a UI controller), you can do this:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
// this, in combination with the token above,
// will ensure that the block is only invoked once
dispatch_async(&onceToken, ^{
    enumTranslations = @{
        @(MyEnumValue1): @"test1",
        @(MyEnumValue2): @"test2"
        // and so on
    };
});




 // alternatively, you can do this as well
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
// this, in combination with the token above,
// will ensure that the block is only invoked once
dispatch_async(&onceToken, ^{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    mutableDict[@(MyEnumValue1)] = @"test1";
    mutableDict[@(MyEnumValue2)] = @"test2";
    // and so on

    enumTranslations = mutableDict;
});
```

If you want this dictionary to be visible externally, move the static declaration to your header (`.h`) file.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. Look at the method signature: `id` specifies an object. An enum type is a scalar. You can't cast from one to the other and expect it to work right. You have to use an object.

Comment: This is true. However, you could wrap the enum value in an NSNumber and use that as the key.